# The NASM has a win API but i try c link NASM an error occurred

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, assembly, nasm

This is NASM code, i can sure the code is normal

use golink to exe can work

```
GLOBAL _echoStr
EXTERN GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA, ExitProcess

SECTION .data
msg                 DB "Hello World!", 13, 10, 0
msg.len             EQU $ - msg
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   EQU -11
NULL                EQU 0

SECTION .bss
dummy   RESD 1

SECTION .text
_echoStr:
    PUSH    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    CALL    GetStdHandle

    PUSH    NULL
    PUSH    dummy
    PUSH    msg.len
    PUSH    msg
    PUSH    EAX
    CALL    WriteConsoleA

    PUSH    NULL
    CALL    ExitProcess
```

This is C code, i think maybe is normal

```
#include <windows.h>

extern void echoStr();

int main()
{
    echoStr();
    return 0;
}
```

Next, i compile NASM

```
nasm test.asm -f win32 -o testF.o
```

Next, i try compile C code and NASM obj file

```
gcc -o main test.c testF.o
```

The ERROR message is

```
C:\C>gcc -o main test.c testF.o
testF.o:test.asm:(.text+0x3): undefined reference to `GetStdHandle'
testF.o:test.asm:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `WriteConsoleA'
testF.o:test.asm:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `ExitProcess'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I not understand ld should be link kernel32.dll

What steps have I lost?

Comment: Try putting an underscore (_) before the names, just like you did with `_echoStr`. You'll probably also have to put an `@` and a number after it as well, like `_GetStdHandle@4`. The number depends on the function, it's the number of bytes of arguments passed on the stack and so is always a multiple of 4.

Comment: @RossRidge I tried your way, but the same error occurs

Comment: I don't see an error message in your question. It would probably help, if you showed us the error message (in full).

Comment: This sort of information should go into your question. You can click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39715333/edit) link to update it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/dLpd5EV.png

Comment: i can't post the image, so.... i post to imgur, sorry

Comment: You can use cut & paste to copy the entire error message as well the the command you typed into in your message as text. Click on the icon in the upper left of the window and select Edit -> Mark. With the mouse select the text in the window you want to copy and then press the Enter key. You can then use CTRL-V to paste it into your post while editing it. Also make sure that when you do this you're using the same source code as in your post. If you since modified it, you'll need to update the post so it includes the actual source code that generates the error messages.

Comment: i update the message, and i can sure that code was true

Comment: When I change `GetStdHandle` to `_GetStdHandle@4`, `WriteConsoleA` to `_WriteConsole@20` and `ExitProcess` to `_ExitProcess@4`, your example code assembles and links without errors for me.

Comment: oh~amaze, can work, can you tell me why how different for EXTERN GetStdHandle and EXTERN _GetStdHandle@4 ?bc, i use EXTERN GetStdHandle can work run win32.exe